# Android AppWidget Battery-Status

Tags: android, widget, broadcastreceiver, android-appwidget, battery

I'm looking for make an AppWidget that check the battery status (level, charging/not charging).

I wrote a lot of codelines, but, even if it work perfectly, I see that put it on the screen make the telephone slower and, sometimes crash.

I think it's because I make something wrong. Can someone help me? Thank's

Here My Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="it.bisneff.widgetone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


       <receiver android:name="MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action 
                    android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>

            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
            </receiver>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

And here my main class:

```
package it.bisneff.widgetone;


import it.bisneff.widgetone.R;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    //Unused String
    private static final String ACTION_CLICK = "ACTION_CLICK"; 


      @Override
      public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
          int[] appWidgetIds) {

        ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
            MyWidgetProvider.class);
        int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

         for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {


                Intent batteryStatus =context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this,
                        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

                    //Battery Level
                int level = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1);

                //Max Battery Level
                int scale = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);

                // %
                float batteryPct = level / (float)scale;
                batteryPct=batteryPct*100;



          RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
              R.layout.widget_layout);

          //Charging or not
          int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);


          boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                  status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

          //integer convertion
          int batteryPctz=(int)batteryPct;
          Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(batteryPctz)+"%");


          //USB or AC charge
          int chargePlug = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
          boolean usbCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
          boolean acCharge = chargePlug == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC;

          //update view
          remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.update, String.valueOf(batteryPctz)+"%");

          //select the image for the battery level
            String res=new String();
            res="it.bisneff.widgetone:drawable/battery";



                    if (batteryPct >= 90)
            {       res+="6";
            }
            if (batteryPct >= 75 && batteryPct < 90)
            {
                res+="5";
            }
            if (batteryPct >= 60 && batteryPct < 75 )
            {
            res+="4";
            }
            if (batteryPct >= 35 && batteryPct < 60 )
            {
            res+="3";
            }
            if (batteryPct >= 15 && batteryPct < 35 )
            {
            res+="2";
            }
            if (batteryPct < 15 )
            {
            res+="1";
            }


          if(isCharging){


            if(acCharge)
            {

                res+="cha";

            }


            if(usbCharge)
            {
            res+="usb";
            }


            if (batteryPctz==100){res="it.bisneff.widgetone:drawable/battery6full";}
          }

            //check the resource
            int reso= context.getResources().getIdentifier(res, null, null);    

            //put the right image
            remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imageView1, reso);



          //Set Click Listener

          Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);

          intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);
          intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

          PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
              0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
          remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.update, pendingIntent);
          appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }

      }


      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       super.onReceive(context, intent);

       //check received intent action
       if(  ((intent.getAction()).equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) || ((intent.getAction()).equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED)) || ((intent.getAction()).equals(Intent.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED))){

           //get Bundle
           Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

           //if extras
           if(extras!=null) {


               AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);         
               ComponentName thisAppWidget = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), MyWidgetProvider.class.getName());
               int[] appWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisAppWidget);

          //call the onUpdate
          onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

         }

       }
      }

      }
```

EDIT:

I see where is the problem.

If I had

```
  ....
        Intent batteryStatus =context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this,
                        new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
            context.getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(this);//this line
     ....
```

The widget stop to loop. But it stop to update on battery level changes...

I added

```
@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context){

    context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));

}
```

to be sure to register my receiver, but it won't work, and I cannot register it from XML cause documentation says it cannot be register there.

How can I do?

Comment: You need to investigate the causes of crash looking for the messages tracked in the logcat. I can suggest also to use try-catch construct in order to avoid crashes, and manage the exception condition.

Comment: Ok. I do that and on first look I see that the widget when put on screen start to run this line Log.w("WidgetExample", String.valueOf(batteryPctz)+"%"); continuosly (it continue to log 84%)

why it do this way?

Comment: Obviously this mean that it continue to call onUpdate().

Comment: My question is, how many times for second an intent is send with action "ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED" ?

This could be the problem. When the phone is active battery level continuosly changes. Obv if the OS send a intent every time the level changes I will get a call every millisecond.

Now I had this

    private int lastbp=0;
    ...
     if(batteryPct!=lastbp)

to stop the application continuos change widget...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Valerio Bisneff Ponza,

You must be facing this exception:

```
android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: BroadcastReceiver components are not allowed to register to receive intents
```

Reason: This is because, you(Widget/ BroadCast Receiver) can not register itself with another Intent_Filter OR register another receiver, from within (Widget/ BroadCast Receiver)...

If you add in manifest, while registering Widget:

- action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" OR
- action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" OR
- action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED" etc.

... most of the times your Widget won't respond.

Reason: Widget is associated with a process(pid) OR service, if run independently(activity/ service) not running, it shall not receive Intents.

WHAT to do THEN??

In On Enabled, start a service, explicitly for updating your widget, register your BroadCast receiver in onStart() of service and update Widget from Service.

NOTE: Please Remember to unregister receiver in onStop() of service, else another exception would come up......And explicitly call stopService() from onDisabled() of Widget. Keep your service as exported="false" in manifest if needed enter code here`d.

Dear Ponza, I have faced that sometimes, your service gets killed by Android, based on some usage based GC. But in that case, we can always have a smart check using some shared Pref boolean in every action of Widget.

HOPE my answer is detailed enough ;)